# Creating a control like Microsoft Office Word's table generator in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Is it possible to create a control like this using HTML5 or `Javascript`? I found the following [link](https://codepen.io/scrimothy/pen/Hqibr) where they create something like a graph using just `CSS`.

```
$trans: transparent;
$block: #00004f;
$line: #19465b;
$gridSize: 60px;
$subdivisions: 1;
$lineAlpha: .1;
$sublineAlpha: 1;
$gridHeight : 120px;

body {
  background-color: $block;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(rgba($line,$sublineAlpha) 1px, $trans 1px), /*sub horiz*/
    linear-gradient($line 1px, $trans 1px), /*main horiz*/
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba($line,$sublineAlpha) 1px, $trans 1px), /*sub vert*/
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba($line,$lineAlpha) 1px, $trans 1px), /*main vert*/
    linear-gradient($trans 3px, $block 3px, $block $gridSize - 2, $trans $gridSize - 2), /*nub horiz*/
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba($line,$lineAlpha) 3px, $trans 3px, $trans $gridHeight - 2, rgba($line,$lineAlpha) $gridSize - 2) /*nub vert*/
    ;
  background-size:    
    $gridHeight / $subdivisions $gridSize / $subdivisions;        
}
```

I'm quite new to `Javascript` development. Is there any third party libraries that are available that will do this for me?

Comment: ofc this is possible with pure javascript and html5. its a great challenge for a beginner, so i wouldn't use any finished libary for this.

Comment: Yeah I know that it's beyond me but I think if I search around I might get a good starting point. Right now my plan is to get first draw a graph in html and get a hover working. Problem is I'm not sure if a regular table would work for this.

Comment: a regular table should work fine - at least you can easily access both row and cell whereas with using just divs would be trickier

Comment: Note that asking for libraries [is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little implementation you could use:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    let [colCount, rowCount] = await tablePicker(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log(JSON.stringify({colCount, rowCount}));
});

function tablePicker(x, y) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let div = document.querySelector("#tblpck");
        if (div) div.remove();
        let colCount = 0;
        let rowCount = 0;
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "tblpck");
        div.innerHTML = `<style>
            #tblpck div{background:#ccc;font-family:Verdana;text-align:right}
            #tblpck table{border-spacing:3px;background:#f8f8f8}
            #tblpck td{border:1px solid #888;width:16px;height:16px;box-sizing:border-box}
            #tblpck .tblpckhighlight{border:2px solid orange;}
        <\/style><div>0x0 Table<\/div>
        <table>${`<tr>${`<td><\/td>`.repeat(10)}<\/tr>`.repeat(10)}<\/table>`;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        Object.assign(div.style, {left: x + "px", top: y + "px", position: "absolute", border: "1px solid #ccc"});
        
        div.onmouseover = (e) => {
            if (e.target.tagName !== "TD") return;
            let td = e.target;
            let tr = td.parentNode;
            let table = tr.parentNode;
            colCount = td.cellIndex+1;
            rowCount = tr.rowIndex+1;
            for (let row of table.rows) {
                let inside = row.rowIndex < rowCount;
                for (let cell of row.cells) {
                    cell.classList.toggle("tblpckhighlight", inside && cell.cellIndex < colCount);
                }
            }
            div.children[1].textContent = `${colCount}x${rowCount} Table`;
            return false;
        };

        div.onmousedown = () => {
            div.remove();
            resolve([colCount, rowCount]);
        };
    });
}
```

```css
body { height: 100vh; margin: 0 }
```

```html
Click to get popup at cursor position...
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is "yes", and actually "yes this should be javascript". That said, not all of it - use css for the visual styling (colors etc). You would learn a ton from making this, so I say go for it. Your HTML will "tell" the browser what element to display (your table), your JS will be for "what happens" (hovers, clicks, info about your table), your CSS will be for the styling. I found this page as an example - https://html-cleaner.com/html-table-generator/